# Have different version of SendEmailAsync

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid, asp.net-identity-2

I am using the default ASP.NET MVC, Identity template... I want to send a confirmation email to my clients.

The default implementation which comes with a new project template, has a Register Method in AccountController.cs

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email.Trim(), Email = model.Email.Trim(), FirstName = model.FirstName.Trim(), LastName = model.LastName.Trim() };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                string message = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message));

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

There is a call to UserManager.SendEmailAsync, now this method is defined in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and I don't want to change it.

The actual send email function is in IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class SendGridEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"];
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("info@mycompany.com", "DX Team"),
            Subject = message.Subject,
            PlainTextContent = message.Body,
            HtmlContent = message.Body
        };

        msg.TemplateId = /* I want to pass templateId here */
        msg.Personalizations[0].Substitutions.Add("confirmurl", /* I want to pass Username here */);
        msg.Personalizations[0].Substitutions.Add("confirmurl", /* I want to pass confirm url here */);

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("info@mycompant.com", "Test User"));
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    }
}
```

Now as you see, I am using Sendgrid to send email... so I don't want a message.body to email... I have made some templates and I I want to pass teplate Id with some substituation tags, like username to be replaced in the template.

So I don't want this generic SendAsync method... I want something like

```
SendGridAsync(SendGridMessage message)
```

Is it possible to add this method, so I can choose when to call SendAsync and when to call SendGridAsync?

Comment: I would look at refactoring the building of the email *content* into a separate service.  You would then call that, and then pass the results into `UserManager.SendEmailAsync(...)`.  Your service then contains the implementation details for each type of email that you want to send.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, but how can I do this? SendAsync accepts only an IdentityMessage, which has Destination, Subject and Body... what I am doing is building a SendGridMessage and I need something like SendGridAsync(SendGridMessage message) but I don't know how to add this...

Comment: Yeah the issue is with the sengrid template.  Thing is, you **don't** need to use `UserManager.SendEmailAsync(...)` to send emails.  You can send the emails from your own service - your implementation doesn't need to implement `IIdentityMessageService`.  Also - you state that you don't want to change the call to `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()` - why not?

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I accept your comment as the right answer, so instead of calling Usermanager.SendEmailAsync, I just need to call SendGridClass.SendEmailAsync with my own implementation? Would you be able to provide a simple demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the built in mail service, especially when you want to do something that's a little more complicated.

Define your own messaging service:

```
public interface IMyMessageService 
{
    Task SendConfirmationMessage(string confirmUrl, string to)
    // define methods for other message types that you want to send
}

public class MyMessageServie : IMyMessageService 
{
    public async Task SendConfirmationMessage(string confirmUrl, string to)
    {
        var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"];
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("info@mycompany.com", "DX Team"),
            Subject = message.Subject,
            PlainTextContent = message.Body,
            HtmlContent = message.Body
        };

        msg.TemplateId = /* I want to pass templateId here */
        msg.Personalizations[0].Substitutions.Add("confirmurl", confirmUrl);

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(to, "Test User"));
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    }
}
```

Register `IMyMessageService` in your DI framework, and inject it into the controller where the emails are being sent from (e.g. the `AccountController`).

Now, your register action would look like this (assumes I've injected `IMyMessageService` and have an instance in `_myMessageService`):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email.Trim(), Email = model.Email.Trim(), FirstName = model.FirstName.Trim(), LastName = model.LastName.Trim() };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            // Send an email with this link
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            // USE YOUR MESSAGE SERVICE
            await _myMessageService.SendConfirmationMessage(callbackUrl, user.Email);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```